# Create a table view with a specific width and height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am implementing a TableViewController. I would like to create the table view with a specific width and height. I tried using initWithFrame and also setting the frame within viewDidLoad. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Are you using initWithFrame or initWithFrame: style:   ?  What is the unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a regular UIViewController and add a Table View in it.
Then resize it either with the interface builder or by setting its frame.

Don't forget to set the table view dataSource and delegate to the view controller.